# How does the RPM Database typically become corrupt?

Tags: linux, rpm

We are automating some deploy scripts which uninstall/install RPMs.  I've seen on more than one of our hosts that rpm -qa returns something like:

```
# rpm -qa | grep tcl
tcl-8.5.7-6.el6.x86_64
tcl-8.5.7-6.el6.x86_64
tcl-8.5.7-6.el6.x86_64
tcl-8.5.7-6.el6.x86_64
tcl-8.5.7-6.el6.x86_64
tcl-8.5.7-6.el6.x86_64
```

How does this happen using rpm -e and rpm -i?  And is there a way to prevent this?  If I run rpm -e in this case, I get

```
# rpm -e tcl-8.5.7-6.el6
error: "tcl-8.5.7-6.el6" specifies multiple packages:
  tcl-8.5.7-6.el6.x86_64
  tcl-8.5.7-6.el6.x86_64
  tcl-8.5.7-6.el6.x86_64
  tcl-8.5.7-6.el6.x86_64
  tcl-8.5.7-6.el6.x86_64
  tcl-8.5.7-6.el6.x86_64
```

So I had to use the `-vv --allmatches --nodeps --noscripts --notriggers` switches

Comment: What are your install scripts _really_ doing?

Comment: When it comes to RPMs, only rpm -i and rpm -e.  After installation and such they might drop config files and start some services, but that's it.

Comment: You sure you aren't using any other switches?

Comment: we do rpm -i ... >/dev/null 2>&1 and same for rpm -e.  No other switches.  Looking @ the script now

Comment: Why the /dev/null redirection?  Don't you *want* to know if there are problems?

Comment: Yea good point - it's basically to reduce clutter, but we should probably just redirect to a log file at the very least.

Answer (score 1):

Anon,

Are you in a position to try `rpm --rebuilddb`, if you haven't already?

http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/rpm.8.html

Alternately, are you in a position to use `yum install`, instead of `rpm`? Yum will usually take better care of your database.

Comment: Yea I have fixed it w/ the rebuilddb and such.  I'm just trying to understand what I'm doing might cause problems.  Yum might be a good option but I just need to make sure it doesn't pull anything down from the net - only the rpms that I want to install

Comment: `yum repolist` will show you the repositories yum is aware of. Then, `yum --disablerepo=<name> ...` will do the installs without an unwanted repositories.

Comment: Sadly we just switched to yum and ran the install/uninstall a few times - we ended up with `Rpmdb checksum is invalid: dCDPT(pkg checksums) ... [ERROR]`

Answer (score 0):

Just To answer how to prevent that (and add to other answer)s, on automated scripts I run dcrpm ( https://github.com/facebookincubator/dcrpm ) before installing software, you install it with pip install dcrpm ... It usually helps with many issues I have